# Modifying objects in your .git folder, expect change on Github after push?

Tags: git, github

If I make a change in my `.git` folder, meaning if I change the `objects/refs/hooks` from the past by hand, and then push that to GitHub, will Github look as if that was history since the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

First, `myrepo/.git/hooks/` is not a folder which would ever get pushed, for security reason.
The last security issue [CVE-2018-11235 git RCE](https://staaldraad.github.io/post/2018-06-03-cve-2018-11235-git-rce/) is a good illustration: you don't want executable running automatically when cloning your repo.

Same for the file `.git/config`: the user configuration remains local.

Second, you are supposed to change files in your local repo, not in your local repo .git folder. A `git status` will tell you what has changed: [git add, git commit and git push](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/#add).

Comment: Hey, I understand that this is unconventional, but I was just toying around and am not using this for my actual work. So is there any way for me to make a change in an object in .git/objects and push it to the remote branch?

Comment: @AndreyLukin I didn't mean that is was "unconventional": I meant that the mere possibility to have that kind of file (hooks) pushed in a repo (as  it was through symlink in a submodule, described in  CVE-2018-11235) was enough for the all industry to stop everything and upgrade their Git in a hurry, hair on fire style.

Comment: @AndreyLukin That being said, you can very well version a hook script in your regular repo (meaning not in .git), push that like any other file, and mention in the README of the repo that this particular file should be copied in .git/hooks by the user after cloning the repo. That is neither conventional nor dangerous; since it requires an explicit action (and review) by the user.